# How to use nspredicate on multiple values on same key

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have an array of dictionaries and i want to get the data which has these values D1, D12, D14

for example:

```
[@{"district":"D1"}, {"district":"D2"}, {"district":"D2"}, {"district":"D12"}, {"district":"D15"}, {"district":"D14"}, {"district":"D14"}, {"district":"D12"}, {"district":"D1"}, {"district":"D18"}, {"district":"D17"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"district IN %@", @[@"D1", @"D12", @"D14"]

Answer (score -1):

```
var resultPredicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate()

resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "district = %@", ["D1","D12","D14"])
```